# ARCHIVE FAILED : After updating Xcode from 9.1 to 10.1

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode10

Archive was getting created with Xcode 9.1 but it is now failing with below error after updating Xcode to 10.1.

```
**ARCHIVE FAILED**

The following build commands failed:
SymLink /Users/rsKRISH/dir/build/Release-iphoneos/Output.app /Users/rsKRISH/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Output-fdnrztthdyjgzvfkiyrgfpahdjxd/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Output/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/Output.app
(1 failure)
```

The command I am using is :

```
xcodebuild -project "$PROJECT_NAME.xcodeproj" -configuration Debug clean build VALID_ARCHS="armv7 arm64" CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR="$PROJECT_PATH/build/Release-iphoneos" -scheme "$PROJECT_NAME" archive -archivePath build/Release-iphoneos/Output.xcarchive
```

I am able to create the archive from Xcode but it is failing while using command line.
And there is no other information about error (error number etc.) in the build log.
Does anybody has any idea, what might be the issue ?

OS: MacOS 10.13.6

Comment: Clean build folder, delete derived data then retry. For sure path does not exists anymore or symlink does not get proper rights to paths.

Comment: I've tried cleaning build folder and deleting derived data. And the path does exist I've checked in the file system. And for proper rights there should be a permission denied error, no ?

Answer (score 0):

After making some changes to the build command. I found out that the issue was caused due to build parameter:

```
CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR="$PROJECT_PATH/build/Release-iphoneos"
```

So, I've removed this parameter for now. But the root cause of the error is still unknown since I haven't received any permission error (or any other error), which can explain the reason why SymLink cannot be created at the given build directory.